# How to input the second line

Tags: java

The file that is begin read from is

```
11 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1 6 7 8 9 10 11
8 -33 -22 -11 44 55 66 77 88
```

11 and 8, the first integer, begin the size of said array. The resulted output, suppose to be an array, is suppose to be two different array base on their first integer size.

I can read and implement the first line of integer using the following code

```
public class sortList{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      try{
      Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data"));
      int[] array = new int[s.nextInt()];
      for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
         if (i == 0){
            continue;
         }
         array[i] = s.nextInt();
         System.out.println(array[i]);
         }

      }
      catch(IOException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Now how do I read the second line of integer, cause i searched everywhere here. No avail

Comment: The continue is redundant if you just set `int i = 1` at the start.

Comment: Conjecture:  Once you've read the entire first array in, then you know it's safe to read the second array in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're literally halfway there.  You've got one loop to go over the first line.  After the first loop has completed, you've effectively exhausted the entire line of text.

What you can do is then advance the scanner to the next line by use of the [`Scanner#nextLine()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) method.

Then, you create another array to store your second line of text similar to the way you created the first.  You don't need to duplicate your `Scanner`.

In actuality, you could write it as a separate, concise method, and only call it when you're ready to populate your arrays.  Outside of the method (after you call it, that is), you'd advance your scanner to the next line.

```
public int[] readLine(Scanner fileReader) {
    int[] array = new int[fileReader.nextInt()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        array[i] = fileReader.nextInt();
    }

    return array;

}
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. didn't think that nextInt() means literally next Integer. When you scan a file and use said file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class sortList{



       public static void main(String args[]){


       try{
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("data.txt"));
            int[] array = new int[s.nextInt()];

            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array[i]);
            }

            s.nextLine();
            int[] array1 = new int[s.nextInt()];
            for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
            array1[i] = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println(array1[i]);
            }

          }

       catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

First, remove these three lines:

```
if (i == 0) {
  continue;
}
```

Then, put a `while (s.hasNextInt()) { … }` (or so, I didn't look up the documentstion) around the `int[] array` and the `}` of the `for` loop.

To see whether it all works, you should then add `System.out.println("one record: " + Arrays.toString(array));` as the last line of the `while` loop.